# React disabling components with fieldset

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, fieldset

I want to disable my components (here is https://ibb.co/2M33Gfc) for this I want to use < fieldset > Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset for more details. I want to know if it's worth using < fieldset > for my components? or is this approach wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't use fieldset for this, doesn't provide any value and is misused component, seems like those are some kind of cards and not label+checkboxes groups.

Comment: You can then advise what to use then instead.?

Comment: Show me some code